# Validate if optional account was passed in

Tags: anchor, solana-program, ata

Let's say I have an account passed in the instruction

```
#[account(mut), constraint = optional_ata.mint = treasury_ata.mint]
pub optional_ata: Option<Account<'info, TokenAccount>>
```

Is this method safe to check if `optional_ata` was passed in?

```
// If optional_ata was passed in
if optional_ata.is_some() {....}
```

IF not, how do I check if `optional_ata` was passed in or not using if statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The normal Rust rules apply on this account, so using `is_some()` is a great way to check if it was passed. The more idiomatic Rust construct is to use `if let` binding, ie:

```
if let Some(account) = optional_account {
// do stuff with the account
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's much easier to make the account mandatory and pass the default Pubkey (`PublicKey.default`) if it is not used. Optional accounts will make it annoying to pass your accounts as arguments.

You might then validate manually instead of with constraints, e.g.:

```
    if *optional_ata.key() == Pubkey::default() {
        Ok(())
    } else {
        // whatever validate you do for "actual" accounts
    }
```